# How to connect several monitors to one computer, and all display the same thing

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have an interesting problem.  I need to have one computer that drives around 30 (Thirty) monitors.  I have a very large room, and need each monitor to have the same thing on them.  I'm open to the idea of wireless since latency isn't a big issue.  Graphics quality doesn't have to be amazing either.  This will mostly be used for powerpoint, excel, word, Maybe some youtube videos at some point.  No sound is needed either.

The basic end goal is to have one computer on a projector that I am driving, and people who are sitting all around the room have monitors they can look at, and they all have the same thing on them.  Any advice on hardware is appreciated.

Comment: Does it count as a duplicate if the question is different, but the answer covers what I needed?  The question asks for the ability for each monitor to show a different desktop.  Mine asks for all the same desktop.  Having said that, I think the answer covers closely to what I need.

Comment: Yes it's the same (IMO), as you asked how to hook up X number of monitors to a single computer.  For future reference, ask about your ACTUAL problem (displaying same thing on 30 monitors) vs. your guessed solution (hooking 30 monitors to one PC). :) Either way include your research, and avoid asking for recommendations regarding hardware/software that does "XYZ", as they are off-topic.

Comment: I did say "that they "all have the same thing on them".  I definitely could have worded it better.  Especially on the title of the question.

Comment: Also, on the title of avoiding recommendations regarding hardware/software.  I've seen that that is considered as off topic here.  Is there a stack exchange site for recommending hardware/software?

Comment: There is a [software recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but not a hardware recs.  If you're going to use the Software Recs site, ensure you read their rules thoroughly on how to ask first (to save yourself a bunch of heartache ;) )

Comment: You could search for "DVI splitter" or "HDMI splitter". The most I saw with a quick look was for 8-way splitting, but once you have found a manufacturer or two you can ask them for suggestions.